# Getting SEVERE: Context [/myapplication] startup failed due to previous errors

Tags: java, tomcat

I am getting this error when starting Tomcat with JDK 7_80, but it is working fine with JDK 6_23. Please find the below console prints and help me to solve this issue.

> INFO: XML validation disabled
>       Jun 16, 2016 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
>       SEVERE: Error listenerStart
>       Jun 16, 2016 2:24:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
>       SEVERE: Context [/myapplication] startup failed due to previous errors

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more information about the version of Tomcat you're using and what your application is doing.

Comment: @MickaëlB, i am using tomcat-5.5.27 and it's a webapplication using jsp files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat requires JDK 5 according to Tomcat 5 release note .

**Tomcat 5 Release note :** http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-5/v5.5.27/

> So you shouldn't use JDK 7 to start your Tomcat 5. You must use JDK 5 to avoid issues.

I suggest you upgrade your Tomcat to an earlier version if you want to use JDK 7.

Comment: Thanks MickaëlB, tomcat7 working but as they mentioned tomcat 5 should support JDK 1.4 and later versions right?

Comment: Yes. But be careful, the "Base distribution" of Tomcat 5 requires JDK7 and there's a "Compatibilty distribution" in addition of "Base distribution" for using tomcat with a Java 1.4 environment.